# Let $W = \{A ∈ M(3, \mathbb{R}) | A = A^T \text{ and } \operatorname{tr}(A) = 0\}.$ Write down a basis for $W.$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I asked a question about basis and dimension earlier, and that arose from this question. Apparently, the dimension is 5 but, I can't wrap my head around why the dimension exceeded 3.

Comment: $M(3,\mathbb{R})$ ist 9 dimensional, since $M(3,\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^9$, so the dimension of $W\subset M(3,\mathbb{R}) $ is at most 9. Why is $W\subset S:= \{ M(3,\mathbb{R}) | A=A^T\}$ 6-dimensional?

Comment: So any vector space when written in the matrix form (mxn) , has a maximum dimension of m.n?

Comment: Yes. As a basis you could use the set of matrices $E_{i,j}$ with $i=1,...m,j=1..n$ which have a zero entry everywhere except at (i,j) where they have a 1. (Similiarly to the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$)

Comment: If there are no other constraints, then yes, a vector space of $m\times n$ matrices is $m\cdot n$ dimensional.

Comment: Great , Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every matrix $A\in W$ can be written in the following form

$$
A(x, y, z, w, t) = \begin{pmatrix}
x & y & z \\
y & w & t \\
z & t & - x - w
\end{pmatrix}
$$

giving us a total of five independent parameters. It is easy to check that the set $$\{A(1, 0, 0, 0, 0),\\ A(0, 1, 0, 0, 0),\\ A(0, 0, 1, 0, 0),\\ A(0, 0, 0, 1, 0),\\ A(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)\}$$

is a basis of $W$.

Comment: So, what would this matrix actually represent? (Ex : A system of three equations can be represented as a 3x3 matrix)

Comment: A general answer is: it represents a [linear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map).

Comment: Thank you so much.